# Charging Mobile through Laptop? Any Ill effects?

Tags: mobile-phone, charging

Is it safe to charge a mobile through a laptop? Are there any ill effects? Can it cause any kind of harm to the laptop and/or mobile? On what factors does it depends?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general there is no problem charging your mobile phone over the USB interface of your laptop.
Read: ExtremeTech: [How USB charging works, or how to avoid blowing up your smartphone](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/115251-how-usb-charging-works-or-how-to-avoid-blowing-up-your-smartphone)

I think a usual safety measure is to avoid placing things like passive USB hubs between the laptop and the mobile phone -- particularly, avoid connecting multiple devices on the same port with such techniques. These days I think even that is covered by the electronics in your laptop (the USB port survives such power pull).

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean through a USB port. There should be no damage.